# How to have one browser with Flash and Java?

Tags: firefox, java, google-chrome, flash

I can't run Java web apps in Chrome/Chromeium and I can't run Flash in Firefox

[image]
[image]

*(Both sites shown in images works in opposite browser)*

Is it possible for me, running Ubuntu 14.10 to use one browser and still be able to use both those sites? I don't care if it is with Chrome, Firefox or something completely else

Answer (score 1):

**[Google Chrome 35 onwards does not support java plugin.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375909)(as of 4 november 2014)
If you want to use java on browser either use [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) or downgrade Chrome to 34 version([backup your bookmarks and settings](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/K2FUB_-cx1I)).**

To enable java in browser, install java by copy and pasting following commands one by one
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y`

**Manual method for users not getting java even after install java by above method**

Follow these instructions to enable Java in your web browser on Ubuntu Linux.
**Google Chrome 34 and previous**

- Become the root user by running the su command and then enter the super-user password. Type:
  `sudo -s`
- Create a directory called plugins if you do not have it. Type:
  `mkdir -p /opt/google/chrome/plugins`
- Go to Google chrome plugins directory before you make the symbolic link. Type:
  `cd /opt/google/chrome/plugins`
- Create a symbolic link. Type:
  `ln -s  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`
- Restart your browser and  [test java](https://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp)

  **Mozilla Firefox**
- Become the root user by running the su command and then enter the super-user password. Type:
  `sudo -s`
- Create a directory called plugins if you do not have it. Type:
  `mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`
- Go to Mozilla plugins directory before you make the symbolic link. Type:
  `cd /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`
- Create a symbolic link. Type:
  `ln -s  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`
- Restart your browser and [test java](https://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp)

---

To enable flash in Firefox you have to install Adobe Flash from Ubuntu Software Center. search for flash in Software center
[image]

Comment: this didn't work. And I checked, I don't even have the folder /usr/local/java

Comment: this means you havent installed java on your machine. install java from this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: As pointed in the question, I already have Java installed and it works in Firefox. Here is a image showing what I've installed: http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202014-11-03%2019:45:05.png

Comment: Chrome 35 onwards does not support java due change in NPAPI. I have updated my answer please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Pepper flash plugin, to do that run this command:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```