# Cannot make work Java 8 Plugin in chrome 39 in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, java, google-chrome, plugins

I cannot make Java 8 work for ubuntu in chrome 39 I already installed the `jdk8` via ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

I also tried creating the symbolic link from google plugins to

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Java plugin working on Google Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470594/how-do-i-get-java-plugin-working-on-google-chrome)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have one browser with Flash and Java?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/545145/how-to-have-one-browser-with-flash-and-java)

Answer (score 2):

**[Google Chrome 35 onwards does not support java plugin.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375909)
If you want to use java on browser either use [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) or downgrade Chrome to 34 version - not recommended([backup your bookmarks and settings](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/K2FUB_-cx1I)).**